# Plastic Ocean avoid IOR distortion, but keep the look

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, physics, glass

I am recreating a model of the ocean in a stylized way.

I am satisfied with the " ocean " look, but I need to place Wind Turbines, and, as expected, I get distortions proper to the IOR transparent mediums.
[image]

**Is there any workaround to get the mesh without the brake?** This is an infographic, and I do not think that realism is helping in this case.

Thank you

Comment: I have to say it is hard for me to understand what whole your Q is about. Refraction (IOR) is the only thing that make you understand you'r observing a water (glass) material. If you prevent IOR appearance, the only thing that left you are color tint and reflections. Probably if you can deep explain what should be preserve and if you can add mockup of desired result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you know distortion is result of IOR value (1.45 by default) ...

[image]

Lowering IOR to something around 1 is not working for you?
Here with IOR 1.1 ...

[image]

Or ... set IOR to 1 to eliminate distortion completely and to get back uncoated surface look, I duplicated the material and assigned to top face with setup - IOR 1.1 and Roughness to 0.5 ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Mmm if you check your sides are different when you lower the IOR.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand whats the point of your comment.

Comment: That 1.1 IOR drastically changes the look of the sides to a point where It is hard to understand is a prism. Looks like surfaces floating without walls.

Answer (score 0):

### View Layers

What you are asking is cheating in any case, so it is hard (and possibly impossible) to get result without any disadvantages ... it will be always question of matter of faked view.

You can try View layers ... but if you want to keep IOR, reflections and shadows it starts to be quite complicated ... Water object is with default IOR 1.45 and there is second Collection with object, Water_Surface and Sand_ShadowCatcher ...

[image]
[image]

[image]